# is there some solution to reduce the time complexity of a program in java?

Tags: java, time-complexity

The question is

> Given a number 'N'. The task is to find the Nth number whose each
> digit is a prime number(<10) i.e 2, 3, 5, 7. In other words you have
> to find nth number of this sequence : 2, 3, 5, 7, 22, 23 ,.. and so
> on.

I'm trying the below code which exceeds the time bound.

```java
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 


class Main {

    public static boolean AlldigitsPrime(int m){
        for(; m>0;){
            int dig=m%10;
            if(dig!=2 && dig!=3 && dig!=5 && dig!=7){
                return false;
            }
            m/=10;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<t; i++){
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            int count=0;
            for(int j=2; j>=2 ; j++){
                if(AlldigitsPrime(j)){
                    count++;
                    if(count==n){
                        System.out.println(j);
                        break ;
                    }
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try constructing the next number directly instead of searching for it. I think there's a pretty tidy algorithm here where you just use concatenation of known-good values to construct.

Comment: t is declared & initialized on the second line of `main(...)` isn't it?

Comment: right. its not finding prime numbers, its finding the Nth digit that is composed of prime numbers. good catch

Comment: but, if so, why are you using j++? You know it can only be 2,3,5 and 7 and nothing else. no 1,4,6,8,9. Maybe store those in an array and refer to it?

Comment: `for(int j=2; j>=2 ; j++){` ..can always(?) terminate?

Comment: pardon me if im wrong, but its still unnecessary iterations? You have to iterate extra cases and check if they fulfill AlldigitsPrime()

Comment: Yes, i see, @CollinD. `t` comes from input... But how is it related to the task/question/problem description??

Comment: Ok, now get it! `t` is number of test cases, ...and loop always terminates

Comment: You have to avoid recalculation (between each t and n!)! Store all known results in a `map<integer, big integer>` (where n is the key, and (prime digits) number is value.

Comment: @xerx593, no my answer was worng, so I deleted it. The reason are the 0es. E. g. 4 (base 10) would be 10 (base 4) which would result in 32 while it should be 22.  Have to think about it again.

Comment: It's a pitty, but still there might/should/must be numerical solution!:) Hats off, @Mihe

Comment: @xerx593, I've updated my answer. Should be correct now.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the n-th number almost directly. The idea is to convert `n` into a new number system in which no number contains a 0 digit (apart from the leading ones which are ignored) but consists only of digits 1 to 4. That is: 1 -> 1, 4 -> 4, 5 -> 11, 6 -> 12, 9 -> 21 and so on. The last step is to replace each digit (1 to 4) by its correspondig prime number (2, 3, 5 or 7).

Although I usually refrain from giving example code for homework, but because it's a bit complicated, I'll show the solution:

```
public int convert(int n) {
    if (n < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive but was " + n);
    int[] primes = {2,3,5,7};
    int result = 0;
    int power = 1;
    do {
        int digit = (n-1) % 4 + 1; // we don't want 0es
        result += primes[digit - 1] * power;
        power *= 10;
        n = (n-1) / 4;             // take the 'removed' 0es into consideration
    } while (n > 0);
    return result;
}
```

Of course, addition and subtraction of 1 in the first two lines of the loop is not necessary but I kept it there to highlight the 'removal' of 0es while calculating the digits.